# Read regexes from file and avoid or undo escaping

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, escaping

I want to read regular expressions from a file, where each line contains a regex:

```
lorem.*
dolor\S*
```

The following code is supposed to read each and append it to a list of regex strings:

```
vocabulary=[]
with open(path, "r") as vocabularyFile:
    for term in vocabularyFile:
        term = term.rstrip()
        vocabulary.append(term)
```

This code seems to escape the `\` special character in the file as `\\`. How can I either avoid escaping or unescape the string so that it can be worked with as if I wrote this?

```
regex = r"dolor\S*"
```

Comment: This is just a visual thing, the string isn't escaped. Verify by typing `r"dolor\S*"` in the REPL (which then also shows `'dolor\\S*'`).

Comment: *This code escapes the \ special character in the file as \\.* No it doesn't. If you *echo* the value, then the Python interpreter would represent the value as `'dolor\\S*'` to make it reproducible, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: When you display the regex, you see '\\' but it is just a representation of the '\' character. There is not need to unescape anything IMHO.

Comment: If you echo the `regex` example string you made, you'll see that it too is escaped when echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused by *echoing the value*. The Python interpreter echoes values by printing the `repr()` function result, and this makes sure to escape any meta characters:

```
>>> regex = r"dolor\S*"
>>> regex
'dolor\\S*'
```

`regex` is still an 8 character string, not 9, and the single character at index 5 is a single backslash:

```
>>> regex[4]
'r'
>>> regex[5]
'\\'
>>> regex[6]
'S'
```

Printing the string writes out all characters verbatim, so no escaping takes place:

```
>>> print(regex)
dolor\S*
```

The same process is applied to the contents of containers, like a `list` or a `dict`:

```
>>> container = [regex, 'foo\nbar']
>>> print(container)
['dolor\\S*', 'foo\nbar']
```

Note that I didn't echo there, I printed. `str(list_object)` produces the same output as `repr(list_object)` here.

If you were to print individual elements from the list, you get the same unescaped result again:

```
>>> print(container[0])
dolor\S*
>>> print(container[1])
foo
bar
```

Note how the `\n` in the second element was written out as a newline now. It is for *that reason* that containers use `repr()` for contents; to make otherwise hard-to-detect or non-printable data visible.

In other words, your strings do *not* contain escaped strings here.